# Pycharm won't add numbers together properly(weird return)

Tags: python

I have a very basic program which adds 2 numbers:

```
def addition(a, b):
    print(a + b)

addition(input("Number 1: "), input("Number 2: "))
```

However, the console doesn't return what I want, not adding the numbers in the way I expect.
EG:

```
Number 1: 2
Number 2: 3
23
```

The console sticks them together as if they are in a list, instead of performing arithmetic! How do I stop this happening? How am I meant to add them arithmetically?

Comment: You should convert the input to `int` before feeding them to the function: `int(input("Number 1"))` ...

Comment: `input()` returns a string.

Comment: `"2" + "3" == "23" `

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are not doing arithmetic. You are concatenating two strings (`"2"` and `"3"`). The result of that is the string `"23"`.

Try this:

```
def addition(a, b):
    print(int(a) + int(b))

addition(input("Number 1"), input("Number 2"))
```